# Find out where my C program hangs with GDB?

Tags: c, gdb

I am trying to debug my C program with `GDB` to find out where it hangs.

As a newbie to `GDB`, I am able to run it, but have no idea how to make `GDB` stop and tell me where the program hangs.

I tried <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> to terminate it but it only shows me

```
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
```

What should I do when the program hangs there in `GDB`?

Comment: To make the gdb stop your program you need to insert breakpoints, this will make the gdb stop the execution of your program at breakpoints. Refer to this article: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/. Google for simple gdb tutorial and refer to it as and when needed.

Comment: @Deepthought Thanks but the problem is I dunno where it hangs. So how am I gonna know where to insert brkpnt?

Comment: Thats exactly the why one uses gdb .... Assume your C program was:   int main() { a(); b(); c()} return 0; ....... You are not sure which function call was responsible for error/crash/hang. Insert breakpoint at line no: where the call to a is made Ex: Entering b 2 in gdb console will insert the breakpoint at line 2. So insert breakpoints at all the line where calls to a b c are made, then run your executable, you will now hit breakpoint and know which call is responsible for hang.

Comment: After the gdb prompt comes just type "run". When it stops type "bt"

Comment: @CharlieBurns: Or the more human-readable: `where`, would do, too... :)

Comment: Would you mind clarifying why you haven't accepted an answer yet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, basic gdb usage is:

- compile with the `-g` flag
- run it in 2 steps: `$ gdb yourProg` and then, in the GDB shell: `gdb) run [arguments]`
- When the program hangs, or terminates, try `gdb) where`, to see where the error occured.
- also use `list` to get an overview of whatever you want

[More on gdb here](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_46.html)
Or refer to [this handy cheat-sheet](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html) of GDB commands.

To know where to set your breakpoints, just compile with `-g` and do this:

```
 $ gdb a.out        //assuming you didn't specify a -o
gdb) run [args]
```

If you don't get your `(gdb)` console-thingy back after the run starts, your program is likely to contain a deadlock. Fix this by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, *then* procede to:

```
gdb) bt            //get a back-trace of where things whent wrong
//or
gdb) where
```

To continue debugging step by step, just use `s`, for example (refer to the cheat sheet... I'm not going to list all commands here)

That should give you some idea as to where to look for problems

Comment: Thanks, I typed gdb) where then it still hangs there... I am in Linux Terminal btw.

Comment: q@mavErick: You don't type `gdb)`, if you run GDB, you get a sort of shell, that, instead of regular bash shell, for example looks like this `(gdb) _` where the `_` is your cursor, that's where you enter the `where` or `bt` commands and the like.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the trouble, I suppose, is if the program hangs (e.g. an infinite loop) you don't get a gdb prompt, and you can't run gdb commands. i.e. you'll have to issue CTRL+C or similar first.

Comment: When it hangs, I have only my cursor `_`. I have `(gdb)` before running it, but when it hangs, I don't have it.

Comment: @Deepthought: Oh deepthought, I humbly beg for forgiveness, I did mean `gdb`... How long 'till we get the ultimate question, BTW? I've written about 1000 progs, that take 42 as an argument, none have worked so far :P

Answer (score 5):

After you've typed <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> within gdb, just type `bt` or `backtrace`, and it'll show you where it was when the program stopped.

Comment: I guess here it will show the trace of signal handler which catch Ctrl + C signal